# How can I return "1-5" if the array is [1,2,3,4,5] in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter, filtering

I am trying to make a program that returns `["1-5"]` if I give `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

I have made it but I can't filter it. So I want a code that will **filter my output code**. Or **any code that is better than mine**.

```js
let array = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11, 34, 56,57,];
let x = [];

for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
    if(array[i] + j == array[j]){
       x.push(array[i] + "-" + array[j]);
    }
    if(array[j] > array[i] + j && array[j + 1]){
      let y = array.slice(j, array.length)
      array = y;
      i, j = 0;
    }
    if(array[i] - array[i + 1] != -1 && array[i + 1] - array[i] != 1 && array[i + 1] != undefined){
      x.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(x);
```

Comment: And what if you give `[1,2,3,4,5, 8,9,10]`? Or `[1,2,3,4,5,12]`? Or even `[1,3,4,5]`? The array in your question seems more complex than the array in your question, and you haven't explained - or even shown - the expected output.

Comment: or `[1,2,5,3]`?

Comment: The output looks wrong. Why does your program output `"1-1"`, `"1-2"` and `"1-3"`? It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume that the list is sorted, we only need to traverse the list sequentially. There's no need to have double-nested loops. If you maintain sufficient states, you can determine whether you are in a group and you merely manage the start versus the last element in the group.

To simplify things I made use of ES6 string interpolation `${start}-${last}`.

```js
let array = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11, 34, 56,57];
let result = [ ];
let hasStart = false;
let start = 0;
let last = 0;
for (let num of array) {
    if (!hasStart) {
        hasStart = true;
        last = start = num;
        continue;
    }
    if (num === last + 1) {
        last = num;
        continue;
    }
    result.push( start === last ? start : `${start}-${last}` );
    last = start = num;
}
if (hasStart) {
    result.push( start === last ? start : `${start}-${last}` );
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The phrasing of the question makes this somewhat difficult to answer, but based on your code snippet I can gather that you are either:

1. Attempting to find the range of the entire array OR
2. Attempting to find contiguous ranges within the array

Based on these interpretations, you could answer this question as follows:

```js
function detectRange(a) {
  // clone a
  const b = [...a]
  // remove first value
  const min = max = b.splice(0, 1)[0]

  // compute range
  const range = b.reduce(({min, max}, i) => {
    if(i < min) min = i
    if(i > max) max = i
    return { min, max }
  }, {min, max})

  return range
}

function detectRanges(a) {
  // clone a
  const b = [...a]
  // remove first value
  const min = max = b.splice(0, 1)[0]

  // init ranges array
  const ranges = [ ]
  // compute ranges
  const range = b.reduce(({min, max}, i) => {
    if(i === max + 1) {
      return {min   , max: i}
    } else {
      ranges.push({min, max})
      return {min: i, max: i}
    }
  }, {min, max})
  // push the remaining range onto the array
  ranges.push(range)

  return ranges
}

function printRange(r) {
  console.log(`["${r.min}-${r.max}"]`)
}

function printRanges(r) {
  r.forEach(i => {
    printRange(i)
  })
}

// detect and print range of whole array
printRange(detectRange([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 34, 56, 57]))
// detect and print only contiguous ranges within array
printRanges(detectRanges([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 34, 56, 57]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Input: [1,2,3,4,5]

Output: ["1-5"]

So I assume you want to get string in format:
`["smallestelement-largestelement"]`

```js
var input1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log( "["+'"'+Math.min(...input1)+"-"+Math.max(...input1)+'"'+"]")
```

If what you want is string in format:
`["firstelement-lastelement"]`

```js
var input1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log( "["+'"'+input1[0]+"-"+input1.pop()+'"'+"]")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an integer array, and if you want to output the range, you could natively [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it (you can also provide rules for sorting) and use [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) for the first element and [`slice(-1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for the last:

```js
let arr = [4,1,5,3].sort();
console.log(arr.shift()+'-'+arr.slice(-1));
```

As said in the comments, you should clarify if you wish `"1-57"` for the snippet array, or describe your use case more broadly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 34, 56, 57];

let s = null;

const result = array.sort((a, b) => a - b).reduce((p, c, i, arr) => {
    if (!s) s = c;
    if (c + 1 !== arr[i + 1]) {
        p.push(s === c ? s : `${s}-${c}`);
        s = null;
    }
    return p
}, [])

console.log(result);
```